# In flexpaper I want to show next and previous page using right and left button using its API

Tags: php, api, flexpaper

I am using this to button using onclick

```
<input type="submit" value="Invoke" onclick="getDocViewer().nextPage()">
<input type="submit" value="Invoke" onclick="getDocViewer().prevPage()">
```

but it throw error 'Cannot call method 'getApi' of undefined'

how do I fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type=submit value="Invoke" 
       onclick="$FlexPaper('id_of_the_documentViewer_element').nextPage()">
<input type=submit value="Invoke" 
       onclick="$FlexPaper('id_of_the_documentViewer_element').prevPage()">
```